# Change the button image when pressed and then released in ios

Tags: objective-c, image, button, nsuserdefaults

I have a button with a image.When this button is pressed, image has to be changed.When the button is pressed again, it should be changed back to original image.
This image changed should be maintained when the view controller is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a button to your `UIView`.

Go into the **storyboard** or **xib** or where ever your button is then **inspector window** and set your image for selected and an image for unselected.

Create an IBAction in the controller and connect the button to that action.

```
-(IBAction) toggleUIButtonImage:(id)sender{
      if ([sender isSelected]) {
         [sender setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [sender setSelected:NO];

         NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [defaults setValue:@"no" forKey:@"buttonSelected"];
         [defaults synchronize];
      } else {
         [sender setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
         [sender setSelected:YES];

         NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
         [defaults setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"buttonSelected"];
         [defaults synchronize];
      }
  }
```

Link that `IBAction` to your button

Then in order to know if it has been selected or not, you need to query `NSUserDefaults` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
- (void) querySelected {
    NSString *selected = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"buttonSelected"];

    if ([selected isEqualToString: @"yes"]) {
        [sender setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [sender setSelected:YES];
    } else {
        [sender setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setSelected:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: This querySelected function has to be called In viewdidload?

Comment: no, it can be called whenever but preferably on viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear. This is because when it gets called it does a check to see whether it was last selected or not and sets the correct image. :)

Comment: Ok will try and see

Comment: Let me know how you get on and if there is anything you need help with.

Comment: did you have any luck?

Comment: in the function queryselcted(),this sender outside the button action is showing error.how to rectify it?

Comment: I think it worked.thanks alot. Any issues will let u know.